# Java Object Attributes

Tags: java, arrays, class, attributes

How do you make an object's attribute an array of objects in java?

assuming I have a class called Card, would this be the right way to do it?:

```
public class DeckOfCards
{
    private Card[] deck; 

    public DeckOfCards()
    {
        deck = new Card[52];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? whether is it correct or not? yes, this can work.

Comment: Yes, it is correct way to have an array of objects as a class  field. But You have to remember that  `deck = new Card[52];` just make on an array of length `52`. `Card` object at any position (e.g. `deck[0]`) will be `null`

Answer (score 0):

This can work but there is obviously no logic to this class yet. You can instantiate a deck of cards but this'd just be a placeholder. The actual objects in the deck Array are still null. You'd need to add some logic, like a function `public void createCards()` or `public void initDeck()`  to assign each index in `deck` a useful reference (card object reference).